# Magento collection object creation from custom query

Tags: magento

I am building a custom module and I would like to create collection object using the three below tables;

Here is the sql query for that, but am stuck when I try to implement in magento as collection object.

```
SELECT 
    `e` . * , `at_color`.`value` AS `color` 
FROM 
    `catalog_product_entity` AS `e`
INNER JOIN 
    `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `at_color` 
ON 
    ( `at_color`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id` )
    AND (`at_color`.`attribute_id` = '92') 
    AND (`at_color`.`store_id` =0) 
INNER JOIN 
    catalog_product_entity_text 
ON 
    catalog_product_entity_text.entity_id = e.entity_id 
    AND catalog_product_entity_text.value LIKE '%jean%'
WHERE
    (at_color.value =6)
```

Please advice how I can join these 3 tables to produce the above result as collection object.

I used below code, but am  getting an error
"Fatal error: Call to undefined method Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection::join() "
 Please let me know if anything wrong with the code. Phpmyadmin produce result for the above sql query.
                $collection = $this->getCollection()
                ->join(array('at_color'=>'catalog_product_entity_int'),'at_color.entity_id=e.entity_id  AND at_color.attribute_id = 92')
                ->join(array('c'=>'catalog_product_entity_text'),'c.entity_id=e.entity_id AND c.value LIKE "%jean%"')->columns(array('value'),'at_color')->where('at_color.value = ?',6);

echo $collection->getSelect();

I am extending model Mage_Catalog_Model_Product to create custom module's model.

Comment: Try to use $this->getCollection()->getSelect()->join(...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since, you are working with Product entity, you don't have to create a custom query, instead try using `addAttributeToFilter()` on Product collection.

For more info on how to use it, visit the [Magento Wiki](https://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/using_collections_in_magento)